# How to create a random letter generator (no repeats) in microsoft excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am required to create a random letter generator that generates 4 letters where repetition is not allowed, on excel for a school assignment. And currently, I am having trouble with the formulas.

So can someone please check this formula and help modify it and tell me what's wrong?

1st Column
=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))

2nd Column [not working]
=SMALL(IF(C3=CHAR({65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90},"",CHAR{65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90}))),CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,89))

I think the 'SMALL' function only works for numbers, I am not sure and all of these I learned from online utube videos.

Comment: What are these set of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

In **A1** enter:

```
=CHAR(64+ROW())
```

and copy downward through **A26**.  In **B1** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

and copy downward.   In **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$26,RANK(B1,$B$1:$B$26,1)+COUNTIF($B$1:$B26,B1)-1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

**NOTE:**

The `COUNTIF()` is there to handle the possibility that `RAND()` may produce a duplicate.